# How to use ec2_sd_config and blackbox exporter for multitarget and multi port service status check.?

Tags: amazon-ec2, prometheus, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

I have 15 EC2 instances and in each system, multiple services are running at different ports (like 443, 8081, 8082, 8000). I need to check whether the services are running smoothly. When i use the blackbox exporter with Prometheus, i need to write multiple jobs for each port or i need to list all the nodes in the target module in the prometheus.yml file. Can i write this in one job with the help of ec2_sd_config and the blackbox exporter by specifying all the ports..??

while using ec2_sd_config, which discover all the ec2 instances, the yml file config is
ec2_sd_configs:

- region: us-east-1
  port: 389

So, only one port can be specified in one job.
If i use the target, then i need to list all the targets, which is not a good practice.

targets:

- [172.10.0.2:389,172.10.0.2:389,172.10.0.4:389,172.10.0.2:8000,172.10.0.2.8000]
  And i need to list all the 15 ec2 instances and ports. Then when a new node comes, i need to add it here, which brakes the dynamic nature.

Please suggest a way to handle it with least number of jobs in prometheus.?

Answer (score 0):

`ec2_sd_config` is for scraping metrics endpoints of the EC2 instances (on a single port).

Unless you are running a Blackbox exporter on each node (which isn't necessary, but is what sets the static port you'd need to scrape), that's not what you want. You'd still need to define the module and target for each exporter /probe request (unless you try to set localhost here).

Instead, you probably want process-exporter on each node collecting service status information, which would run on a single port, so can be used with ec2_sd_config